# how to set 2 inputs to have min width when inline?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I would like to display my clients first and last name in 2 different inputs in the center of the client page and give each input a minimum width to avoid extra spacing between the two.

I've tried to use min-width or use the "size" attribute for the inputs but it's causing problems when the first input has too much characters.

```html
     <div className="input-client-name">
          <input value={this.state.fname}/>
          <input value={this.state.lname}/>
     </div>
```

```css
.input-client-name {
    display: flex;
}

.input-client-name input {
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: min-content;
}
```

I expect the output of:  " firstName LastName " without worrying from the characters length of each of the ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with `flexbox`, it's advised to not play with `width` since we flexbox for achieving responsive behaviour and setting `width` (even `max` and `min` widths) to a value defeats that purpose.

Since you want input boxes displayed side-by-side, and based on window size - you may want to wrap second input box to next line - add a `flex-flow` to your parent.

```css
.input-client-name {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

> `flex-flow` is a combination of `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` properties.

Next, you want to give a min width to your input boxes, you can achieve this by using `flex-basis` - which works as an initial size for your element.

```css
.input-client-name input {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

> Note: `margin` is added as space between two input boxes. You can choose to use `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-evenly` for same purpose.

*Additional references:*

A demo fiddle for this is availale [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xnfpjus7/10/).

Want to learn more about flexbox? Read a nice article on it [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-flexbox-everything-you-need-to-know-b4013d4dc9af/).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being closed as 'low quality', please add some explanatory text.